# Because setState() does not change values

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was working on my code and the setstate was working correctly until after trying to make other changes the setState was no longer changing the values of the variables. What could this be due to?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:weather/weather.dart';
import 'package:weatherapk/widgets/customs_color.dart';
import '../controller/global_controller.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TemperatureWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TemperatureWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TemperatureWidget> createState() => _TemperatureWidgetState();
}

class _TemperatureWidgetState extends State<TemperatureWidget> {
  RxString iconText = "".obs;
  RxDouble temperature = 0.0.obs;
  final GlobalController globalController =
      Get.put(GlobalController(), permanent: true);

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAddress();
    super.initState();
  }

  getAddress() async {
    WeatherFactory wf = WeatherFactory("fbe4f636d052c6acacb97519f02e3b99",
        language: Language.SPANISH);
    Weather w = await wf.currentWeatherByLocation(
        globalController.getLatitude().value,
        globalController.getlongitude().value);
    setState(() {
      iconText.value = "10d";
      iconText.refresh();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
      Image.network(
        "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${iconText.value}@2x.png",
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 1,
        color: CustomColors.dividerline,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

I searched similar forums and tried WidgetisBinding and it still didn't give that replacement.

Comment: you're using Getx observables .obs outside of a GetxController without using Obx.

Comment: I have already changed the GetX but still no changes. in the onInit it manages to change but not inside the setState().

Comment: I just placed a print() inside the setState() and it did not load in the terminal.

Comment: are you trying  to get with getx or setState ?

Comment: Also, might not make much of a difference, but super.initState() must always come at the *beginning* of your override of initState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAddress` is a `Future` method, it will take some frame to get data. It is better and recommend to use `FutureBuider` for this case. For now I am just calling setState after receiving date and without getx.

```
class _TemperatureWidgetState extends State<TemperatureWidget> {
  String iconText = "";
  double temperature = 0.0;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAddress();
  }

  getAddress() async {
    WeatherFactory wf = WeatherFactory("fbe4f636d052c6acacb97519f02e3b99",
        language: Language.SPANISH);
    Weather w = await wf.currentWeatherByLocation(
        globalController.getLatitude().value,
        globalController.getlongitude().value);
    setState(() {
      iconText = "10d";
    });
  }
```

Just use `iconText`, initial frame may show image error, depend on api.